# How to create half height borders either within or between table cells

Tags: html, css

I need a half-height border between table cells or some half-cell-height vertical lines within a cell - the result should look as follows:

[image]

I have tried using `line-height` on the `td` element as in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/byronj/gLcqu6mg/), but this does not work when specifying `height` either on the `tr` element or the `td` element.

I have also tried using `repeating-linear-gradient` [as shown here](https://jsfiddle.net/blyth/k68j54bv/5/), but I cannot make the vertical lines "half-height".

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please put the code you have tried directly into your question as external links can disappear (or get debugged) thus rendering your qestion useless to future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4):

Use a pseudo-element instead of an actual border.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 2em;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

td:not(td:last-child)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  background: green;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid green;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can position and size and repeat/no-repeat the linear-gradient image:

```css
.grid {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue 0 1px, transparent 1px 100%);
  background-size: 20% 50%;
  background-position: 0 bottom;
  height: 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
}

td {
  width: 10em;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

tr {
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="grid"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```